# Phase transition in superconductors

Tags: condensed-matter, phase-transition, superconductivity

I wonder about how the phase transition in type 1 superconductors work. How the magnetic flux gets expelled in the phase transition. I am trying to understand the mechanisms behind this phenomenon. I will really appreciate an answer.

Comment: This is indeed an interesting topic, but your question is very broad. You need to make it more specific for SE. You should specify if you would like "hand-waving" explanation or some more rigorous calculations. Anyway, you need to specify what do you know already (BCS theory?).

Comment: Hey! I am familiar with the BCS theory. The problem that I have is about understandig how the meissner effect works, How the magnetic flux is expulsed from the inside of the supercondcutor when it  reaches its transition temperature in an applied magnetic field. There is not change in magnetic flux!!

Comment: an answer that I got states "The reason for this expulsion is due to the superconductor going through a phase transition in which the microscopic description of the material changes. The electromagnetic field propagates in a different way when the material becomes superconducting, and it follows the London equations, which show an exponential damping of the field" But it doesn't really explain the mechanisms behind the expulsion, how the microscopical description of the material changes  and so on.

Comment: I am a high school student so I don't think that I will understand advanced calculations or mathematicals equations that has to do with the topic. But I have read a lot about superconductors  so there is no need to oversimplify. I will try my best to understand if you decide to answer, It will really help a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

tldr; Circulating supercurrents on the surface of the superconductor cause there to be zero magnetic flux inside the material.

If I understood your question correctly, you would like to know the mechanism behind flux exclusion in superconductors? I will try to go easy on the maths as per your request. I will limit my answer to type I superconductors.

Superconductors expel all magnetic fields (except in a [thin surface layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_penetration_depth)) due to the [Meissner effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissner_effect). When materials are cooled below their superconducting transition temperature $T_{\rm{sc}}$ they become perfectly [diamagnetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamagnetism) (diamagnetic materials are repelled by a magnetic field; an applied magnetic field creates an induced magnetic field in them in the opposite direction). A magnet atop a superconductor which rises spontaneously when the superconductor is cooled below $T_{\rm{sc}}$ is a demonstration of the Meissner effect.

In your comment you mention that "there is no change in magnetic flux" - It is correct that there is no change in the applied magnetic flux ($\Phi = BA$) **outside** the superconductor. The magnetic $B$ field and the area $A$ do not change. The magnetic flux **inside** the superconductor does change; Emperically we know flux is excluded internally i.e. $\Phi_\rm{i} = 0$ (recall our experiment with the magnet atop a superconductor).

One mechanism to consider flux exclusion is **screening current diamagnetism**. Below $T_{\rm{sc}}$ the applied $B$ field is repeled due to a surface supercurrent which creates a $B$ field inside the material that exactly cancels the one from outside.

$$B=0 \Rightarrow \Phi_\rm{i} = 0$$

In summary, supercurrents flowing on the suface of the superconductor cause magnetic flux inside the material to be excluded. Elecrical currents and the magnetic field they induce are related by the "right hand rule". The direction and magnitude of the surface current is determined by Amepere's Law, such that the internal flux is excluded.

Note: the current flows only on the surface of the material, not in the bulk. We can see this from Maxwell's third law $$\nabla  \times \vec{B} = \mu_\rm{0} \vec{j}$$ Since $\vec{B} =  0 \rightarrow \nabla  \times \vec{B} = 0 \rightarrow \vec{j} = 0 $. However $\vec{B} \neq 0$ outside the superconductor and perpendicular magnetic field lines must be continous ([Gauss' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem)) which means current must flow on the surface (as there is no current in free space).

Please let me know if my explanation is not clear. I can add some more explanation or a diagram tomorrow if neccesary. I will try find further reading and add it to the post tomorrow.

Comment: The static (energy)  issues are well understod, but the actual dynamical process is *not* understood. Exploring this  would be a good PhD topic.

Comment: Hi @mikestone, thanks for your comment. That's a very interesting point. Can we talk about this further? Do you mean we don't have a theoretical description for the onset of flux exclusion? Do we have experimental evidence showing these circulating surface supercurrents? Has there been much research in measuring their formation in the lab?

Comment: What I mean is that the actual dynamics (time dependence) of the onset of pairing, and of the subsequent evolution of the condensate is still an active topic of research --- both theoretical and experimental.